# How to override email/items.phtml and email/items/default.phtml to include product url and thumbnail in magento2.1.3

Tags: overrides, magento-2.1.3, items, order-confirmation

I have developed one module in magento-2.1.3. on the name of **Shelltag/SalesOrder/**. I want to override `items.phtml` file and `default.html` from module-sales/ in this. I don't want to edit core file.

So, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override from your theme

For Creating Theme follow[this link](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-theme-create-sample-custome-theme/)

after creating your theme just copy paste the below files into your theme.

For Example:

```
app/design/frontend/ABCCompany/BranchOne/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/ABCCompany/BranchOne/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/default.phtml
```

Comment: ok but how to do it .i want process..iam a newbie to magento and have rare idea to override phtml files so kindly help me to override my both files items.phtml & default along with full steps.like to create xml files and so & so.

Comment: @YogeshRaghav First you have to know/learn  how to create theme. then only you know how to do it this task?

Comment: well i just want to override my two files items.phtml and default.phtml and not creating child themes for now.iam just asking the procedure..i know we have to create a folder in app/code and put in module.xml file in etc but i have less idea about exact process so kindly help me.its urgent as my company need to shift on magento and we are still in development phase

Comment: @YogeshRaghav see updated answer.

Comment: @YogeshRaghav have you done?

Comment: not yet sir my sire has told me to finish this within 2 hours thats y still working on it and getting no results

Comment: @YogeshRaghav just copy paste code as I given link. and run the `setup` and `clean` commands it will work.

Comment: from where to copy sir?iam not seeing any new update?

Comment: @YogeshRaghav http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-theme-create-sample-custome-theme/